# Automatically truncating strings in NHibernate / SQL Server

Tags: nhibernate

I have a nvarchar(2000) column in a SQL Server 2005 database, and have mapped this into NHibernate as:

```
<property name="Query" column="`Query`" type="String" length="2000" not-null="false"/>
```

The DTO class just presents a string property:

```
    public virtual string Query { get; set; }
```

If I set the query to a string of > 2000 characters I get an exception from SQL server to the effect of:

> "String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated."

What I want is for this truncation to just happen automatically and silently.  I could override the virtual property and force the truncation on the property set, but feel there should be a way to get this behaviour by default, either via the NHibernate mapping or even as a SQL server setting.

Am I missing anything ... I don't want to change the db schema to allow longer strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom User Type and which truncates the string if it's longer than 2000 chars. Here is sample of [creating User Type](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx)

```
<property name="Query" type="Common.Nhibernate.Types.StringTruncType, Common" column="`Query`" type="String" length="2000" not-null="false"/>
```