# fluent nhibernate truncate string automatically

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there an easy way to automatically truncate strings using fluent nHibernate mappings.  I would prefer to not address this the setters or a custom type, but with something in the mapping files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to make sure strings persisted to the database are no longer than a specified length.  This sounds like it could be a business concern though and probably does belong in the domain model or as validation logic.

This question appears to have been asked before and the solution was a custom nHibernate UserType.  Keep in mind this isn't a custom entity type or base class, this is a custom mapping type that nHibernate can understand.
[Automatically truncating strings in NHibernate / SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831452/automatically-truncating-strings-in-nhibernate-sql-server)

If the custom usertype solution isn't to your liking then you could implement a custom interceptor, but I don't believe there is anything in nHibernate that does this "out-of-the-box".  However, that is the beauty of nHibernate is that it is very extensible and implementing a custom user type for your situation is not difficult at all.

Comment: my thoughts on the matter is that a custom mapping type is alot of work for every string that has a different length.  

I also think that my db field length restrictions shouldn't end up in my domain model, although that is the current solution.

I haven't looked at the custom interceptor, but I guess it is going to require customization for every mapped field.

I did see the above post, and I didn't like the solution.  I also saw another post from 2007 here: https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2384695&sid=acd46382cedafad0bc08064e318ecfce that lead me to believe this is possible.

Comment: You shouldn't have to have a type for every length, you just set the string length property in the mapping.  If you are trying to avoid setting the string length in the mapping I think you may be out of luck, I don't think nHibernate has any way to know what the SQL string length settings are.

Comment: One other option would be using a custom nHibernate validator attribute on your model properties as another way to do this something like:

  [Truncate(length = 25)]
  public string StringProperty { get; set;}

Even without nHibernate validators the attribute could be used with a very simple nHibernate interceptor.  If you want an example of that let me know.